# UIPasteboard not cleaned up

Tags: ios, uipasteboard

I have two apps that use an assortment of UIPasteboard names as a scheme to share data between each other.

The pasteboards use the reverse DNS naming convention, like so: `com.mycompany.myapp.stuffx, com.mycompany.myapp.stuffy`

All the apps that use these pasteboards belong to the `com.mycompany` namespace.

When I uninstall app A the data that was stored in the pasteboards, as expected, lives on. After I uninstall app B, effectively removing all apps that use the pasteboards, I expect any associated data/pasteboards to be cleaned up as the documentation of the persistent property suggest this. However, this does not happen; after I reinstall an app, it is still able to access the old pasteboard data.

The pasteboards are created by whatever app needs it first and have their `persistent` property set to true. Is it possible to ensure the old pasteboard data is cleaned up if nothing is using it anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should open a bug with Apple on this.

http://bugreport.apple.com

As you said the documentation states that the pasteboard should be removed when the application that created it is uninstalled, and that's not happening for you.

Comment: That's what I will do. Thanks!

Comment: @jverrijt what do they say? It still behaves like you did described in your problem. Im using iPhone 5S iOS 7.1

Answer (score 0):

i think this is expected behavior

"effectively removing all apps that use the pasteboards" - and how is the system supposed to know that?

i suggest performing some special action on first launch after install, you can test if you're the first app of your special app group to be installed and clear out the pasteboards

Comment: Apple's documentation says "A persistent application pasteboard is removed when the application that created it is uninstalled.".  This is the documentation for the persistent property on UIPasteboard.

Comment: (from those docs) If app A creates the pasteboard, I would expect it to be deleted when A is deleted. even if app B has read or written to it since then. (not post-exist as you are expecting)

Comment: I would agree with @stevex, that you should open this as a bug. Preferably after recreating it with the most minimal app/s that can recreate it. - they could very well just modify the docs, so in the mean time, i'd code a workaround.